# Read io.BytesIO with Pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas, bytesio

I am totally new in Python and I am following a google drive tutorial to be able to read a file from the cloud:

```
def download_file(real_file_id):

    try:
        service = authorize()
        file_id = real_file_id

        # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
        request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
        file = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(file, request)
        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            print(F'Download {int(status.progress() * 100)}.')

    except HttpError as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
        file = None

    return file.seek(0)
```

Then I am trying to read this file with pandas read_csv method:

```
def read_file(item):
    with open(item, 'rb') as file:
        csvreader = pd.read_csv(file.read())
        print(csvreader)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file = download_file("file_id")
    read_file(file)
```

I am sure the download method is working because is tested but when I try to read with pandas it just hang and nothing happens... I need to cancel the script manually and I got this errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tluce\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 23, in <module>
    read_file(download_file(files[0]['id']))
  File "C:\Users\tluce\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 15, in read_file
    csvreader = pd.read_csv(file)
  File "C:\Users\tluce\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 912, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\tluce\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 577, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\tluce\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1407, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\tluce\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1679, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\tluce\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 93, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 548, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 637, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 848, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 859, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._check_tokenize_status
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2025, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'.
```

Answer (score 0):

First: `seek()` returns the new absolute position of the bytes io as an integer. It does not return the bytes io object. You will need to call `file.seek(0)` on one line, and then `return file` on the next. For reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek

Second: you can pass the BytesIO object directly into `read_csv`. Try replace your `read_file` function with:

```
def read_file(file_bytesio):
        csvreader = pd.read_csv(file_bytesio)
        print(csvreader)
```

Here's a short example for you try out yourself!

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    ["cheeta", 100],
    ["snail", 1]
],
columns=["animal", "speed"])

with io.BytesIO() as csv_buffer:
    df.to_csv(path_or_buf=csv_buffer)
    csv_buffer.seek(0)

    new_df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=csv_buffer)
    print(new_df)
```